# How to break string by character and line length, without breaking words?

Tags: c#, string, split, break, line-breaks

I want to break a long string by character and line length, without breaking words.
Within my string I use "|" as my seperator, and every line must never end with a seperator. I need to break on "|", without breaking words.

I tried the following, which looks at the maximum line length, and makes sure everything fits. Now I have to implement the seperation by "|" character without interupting the check for line length.

```
int partLength = 35;
string sentence = "Silver badges are awarded for longer term goals. Silver badges are uncommon.";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
var parts = new Dictionary<int, string>();
string part = string.Empty;
int partCounter = 0;

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            if (part.Length + word.Length < partLength)
            {
                part += string.IsNullOrEmpty(part) ? word : " " + word;
            }
            else
            {
                parts.Add(partCounter, part);
                part = word;
                partCounter++;
            }
        }
        parts.Add(partCounter, part);
        foreach (var item in parts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
```

I tried the following for breaking by character "|":

```
string sentence = "The dog had a bone | a ball | and other toys.";
        char charToTrim = '|';
        string[] words = sentence.Split();
        foreach (string word in words)
           Console.WriteLine(word.TrimEnd(charToTrim));
```

This will print all words on new line, which is not correct.
So in a long text, I need to look at the maximum line length, as well as the seperator "|". The words must match within the line, but a new line cannot end with "|".

So the following is correct:

> Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4
>   | Item 5 | Etc

But the following is not correct:

> Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 |
>   Item 5 | Etc

Comment: What if you provide multiple chars to Split method in your original solution? It accepts char[], so you could write: string[] words = sentence.Split(new [] { ' ', '|' });

Comment: But if I do that, it will always split on "|", even if there is still room for more words

Comment: Then it's not clear to me what you want exactly. Is it only about trimming "|" from the line end? Or you want to get rid of "|" in the text completely?

Comment: I want to break whenever there is no more space in the line (since there is a maximum line length set in code). The words must not break. But, a line must never end with "|"

Comment: So whenever there is no more space for a specific word, if there is a seperator "|" it must also go to the new line even if there is space for it on the previous one

Comment: Basically you want to treat the `| ` (separator + space) as part of the word that follows it.  One easy solution would be to replace the space after the `|` with an invisible character that is not a space, like the the [Unicode Braille Pattern Blank](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2800).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't split the string using the `|` as you would lose the information about where they existing in the original string. Also you won't be able to do this with `foreach` as you need to look ahead when calculating the length of the next string. Taking your original code you can do this:

```
int partLength = 35;
string sentence = "Item 1 | Item 2 | Item 3 | Item 4 | Item 5 | Etc";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
var parts = new Dictionary<int, string>();
string part = string.Empty;
int partCounter = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < words.Count(); i++)
{
    var newLength = part.Length + words[i].Length;

    if(words[i] == "|" && i + 1 < words.Count())
    {
        newLength += words[i + 1].Length;
    }

    if (newLength < partLength)
    {
        part += string.IsNullOrEmpty(part) ? words[i] : " " + words[i];
    }
    else
    {
        parts.Add(partCounter, part);
        part = words[i];
        partCounter++;
    }
}
parts.Add(partCounter, part);
foreach (var item in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
}
```

We still split on a space but we use a `for` loop to iterate through the strings. Before we check if the current word fits we need to check if it is a `|`. If it is then add the next word as well (if one exists). This should produce the output you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying your example (and following your initial approach) I was able to do it like this (the idea is to look one more word ahead in case we meet the separator):

```
int partLength = 15;
string sentence = "Item1 | Item2 | Item3 | Item4 | Item5 | Item6 | Item7 |";
string[] words = sentence.Split(' ');
var parts = new List<string>();
var partBuilder = new StringBuilder(partLength);
int partCounter = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
{
    var word = words[i];
    var nextWord = (i < words.Length - 1) 
        ? words[i + 1]
        : null;
    var lengthToCheck = 
        word == "|" && nextWord != null
            ? word.Length + nextWord.Length
            : word.Length;

    if (partBuilder.Length + lengthToCheck < partLength)
    {
        if (partBuilder.Length > 0)
            partBuilder.Append(" ");
        partBuilder.Append(word);
    }
    else
    {
        parts.Add(partBuilder.ToString());
        partBuilder.Clear();
        partBuilder.Append(word);
        partCounter++;
    }
}
parts.Add(partBuilder.ToString());

foreach (var item in parts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

The output is:

```
Item1 | Item2
| Item3 | Item4
| Item5 | Item6
| Item7 |
```

I also replaced concatenation of strings by *StringBuilder* which is considered the best practice when it comes to concatenating a lot of strings.

And I still have guts feeling that it's even easier to solve this by moving through the string char by char.